# Destructing array returned by asynchronous function shows typescript error

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, async-await

Consider following example TypeScript code

```
const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {resolve([47, undefined])})
const asy = async () => {const [a, b] = await p; console.log(a, b)}
asy()
```

When I run it in `node` without checking types, it runs fine and prints `47 undefined`. However, typechecker in *VS Code* underlines `[a, b]` with following error: `Type 'unknown' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488)`.

How can I fix this error and why this happens? I thought any valid JavaScript code should be valid TypeScript code.

edit: Adding `as any` after awaiting is *a* solution.

Comment: _"...any valid TypeScript code should transpile into valid JavaScript code"_, ftfy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The promise is infered as `Promise<unknown>` because Typescript doesn't infer Promise resolve types.
And you can't destructure `unknown`, because it might not be destructible.

You can explicitly type it:

```
const p = new Promise<[number, undefined]>((resolve, reject) => { resolve([47, undefined]) })
const asy = async () => { const [a, b] = await p; console.log(a) }
asy();
```